# Combination of lens

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

[image]

In the above diagram, let the refractive index of concave lens be $n_1$ and of convex be $n_2$.So in order to apply lens maker formulae for it, will I have to assume air separation between the lens?

What happens if there is another medium between the lens? Will that medium act like another lens because light rays will refract from it like that of a lens?

Comment: Of course it does affect, you can do the math. You can work with $H$ and $H'$ for thick lenses in non-air media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.You don't need to consider air separation between them unless it is specified.
If there happens to be a different medium between them then that medium will act refract the rays.